# Enable xDebug for a webhook

Tags: php, apache, xdebug, webhooks

I know that xDebug can be enabled (if configured so) to be enabled when a certain cookie is sent along.

I have the case now that a PHP script is being called through a remote server (webhook). Is it possible to enable xDebug through a PHP function call that I can place at the beginning of the PHP file to be called by the webhook?

Or is there any other possibility to enable xDebug for that webhook?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, figured something out.
One can simply append the GET parameter "XDEBUG_SESSION_START" to the URL being called by the webhook to enable xDebug.

Comment: don't forget to add =1 ({url}?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, assuming you're running Xdebug 3 (which you most likely will be in 2023), and you have access to the xdebug configuration, you can enable `start_with_request`.

In my setup (IndigoStack) the file is at `conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`. You need to add the following line:

`xdebug.start_with_request=yes`

Read more here: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide